# Не могу установить/включить/загрузить драйвер FTDI под linux (armbian)

Tags: linux, arm, com-порт, armbian-linux

Мы переносим ПО на ОС Armbian Linux. В старой (работающей) системе было доступно устройство `/dev/ttyUSB0`, через него было коммуникация с ком-портом. В Armbian в `/dev` нет этого устройства. Прочитал, что должен работать драйвер FTDI.

В старой системе даю `dmesg | grep FTDI` и получаю:

```
[   18.878338] USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   18.898497] ftdi_sio 5-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   18.961458] usb 5-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   18.974874] ftdi_sio: v1.6.0:USB FTDI Serial Converters Driver
```

т.е. все работает. Тоже самое делаю в Armbian (`dmesg | grep FTDI`) - пустота:

```
root@olinuxino:/boot# dmesg | grep FTDI
root@olinuxino:/boot#
```

Прочитал, что нужно проверить `/boot/config-<version>`, мол там может не быть строки `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_FTDI_SIO`. Делаю:

```
cat config-4.19.17-sunxi | grep USB | grep SER
```

получаю, среди прочего:

```
...
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_FTDI_SIO=m
...
```

Ага! Что же это за 'm'? Гуглю, нахожу, что это значить,что драйвер скомпилирован в виде загружаемого модуля и ядро загружает этот модуль "по требованию" (есть еще 'y' и 'n'). В этом и состоит вопрос, как его "загрузить", чтобы устройство `/dev/ttyUSB0` появилось?

Comment: это `m` означает, что драйвер при **сборке ядра** собран как «модуль», обычно такие модули устанавливаются в `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`. В нормальных условиях они должны автомагически загружаться, например, при добавлении устройства на usb шину... почему этого не происходит в конкретном случае — сложный вопрос и требует дополнительного анализа... начать можно с того чтобы просмотреть вывод `lsusb` на обеих системах, проверить, что модуль действительно установлен и, например, просто загрузить его вручную с помощью `modprobe ftdi_sio`.

Comment: дал `modprobe ftdi_sio` и на `dmesg | grep FTDI` теперь появляется `[ 6828.799551] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device` - уже прогресс! Но никакого `/dev/ttyUSB0` что то не появилось. Может дописать его в `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`?

Comment: можешь, но скорей всего принципиально это ничего не изменит=)... собственно надо смотреть, что это за устройство и что происходит на usb... например, если это какой-то китайский 3G свисток, то некоторые из них любят по-умолчанию определяться только как виртуальные cd-rom'ы и только при некоторых условиях переключаться в режим модема, меняя VID/PID...

Comment: ты был прав, не помогло... Что бы еще предпринять?..

Comment: нум, повторюсь, стоит сравнить вывод `lsusb`, внимание на ID устройств, далее, если различается, то плясать от того, что же это за устройство... также проверь, что usb на плате вообще работает...

Comment: Посмотрите на вывод `lsusb`, погуглите по USB vendor ID и device ID, кем представляется ваше устройство.

Comment: голосую за закрытие вопроса, пожалуйста проголосуйте у кого хватает прав, решение оказалось слишком частным, маловероятно будет кому-то интересным. Однако узнал много нового (огромное спасибо @Fat-Zer за ценные комментарии), поэтому не удаляю

Comment: @asianirish лучше ответ опубликуйте. неинтересные вопросы не просто тонут в нулях, а могут и помочь кому-то.

Comment: модпроба явно не помогла бы, потому что удев уже все посмотрел и модпробнул что нужно после загрузки. usb-modeswitch помогает с модемами и принтерами, но тут же не модем) вон у меня валяется тонкий клиент с армбиан на линукс 2.6 - хотел его как-то запустить на третьем ядре не определилась видюха, может осенью на пятом попробую...